# How do i explain the difference of correlation between mean income and total income?

Tags: correlation, simpsons-paradox

I am doing a report on the complaints made to the municipality by the people of an italian city. I'm doing the part of the analysis where I try to understand where people complain the most.
The municipality provides data for 90 statistical areas that they have divided up.
In the dataset on income per statistical area, the municipality makes available data on the number of taxpayers and the total taxable income for that statistical area (not the per capita, the sum).
Now, I plotted the number of reports vs. the total taxable income and got this (cor = 0.93)
[image: complaints vs total]

Then I plotted against the average income (obtained by dividing the total sum of incomes / n taxpayers) and got this (cor = -0.0002385297)

[image: complaints vs mean]

What's going on? How can these results be explained? Is this simpson's paradox?
Furthermore, which data best describe the reality?

Comment: One possible explanation could be that the higher the total income of an area the higher the number of people in this area ==> higher number of complaints, which does not reflect in the average income but I may be wrong

Comment: I think it's a good explanation and actually it turns out mine was a lazy question :D. Reality is, there's no correlation between income and complaints but it is almost perfect between number of people living in an area and complaints. And the latter is actually pretty obvious

Comment: @periwinkle: That looks like an answer, can you make it one (by writing in the answer box)